# Hibernate 3 sessionFactory in Spring Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 3.3 and Spring 3.2 through java configuration. I would like to create a session factory in my application context. I'm trying something like this

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws Exception {
    AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.package" });

    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer", false);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.check_nullability", false);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners", false);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

    return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

But in the last line it returns `null` ¿What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if AnnotationSessionFactoryBean works if you directly create a new instance of it. Try instantiating it with dependency injection instead. Eg: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-annotation-mysql-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before returning the `SesionFactory`, you need to make a call to [afterPropertiesSet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/AbstractSessionFactoryBean.html#afterPropertiesSet%28%29):

```
sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
```

which builds and exposes the `SessionFactory`.